# Does using the Artificer's Repulsion Shield happen before or after taking damage from a successful hit?

Tags: dnd-5e, artificer, artificer-infusions

Does using the Artificer's Repulsion Shield prevent the character from taking damage? Or does it happen after taking damage from a successful hit?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### Your artificer takes the damage

The rules for repulsion shield reads as follow:

> A creature gains a +1 bonus to Armor Class while wielding this shield.
>
> The shield has 4 charges. While holding it, the wielder can use a reaction immediately after being hit by a melee attack to expend 1 of the shield's charges and push the attacker up to 15 feet away. The shield regains 1d4 expended charges daily at dawn.

The trigger is "after being hit by a melee attack". Once you are hit, you take damage. The only exception would be if the rules included a possible way to avoid the damage (by avoiding the hit) like the [shield](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/shield) spell.

Answer (score 5):

#### You still take the damage.

Repulsion Shield states:

> While holding it, the wielder can use a reaction immediately after being hit by a melee attack to expend 1 of the shield’s charges and push the attacker up to 15 feet away.

You were still hit by the attack, and the rules for “Making an Attack” say:

> You make the attack roll. On a hit, you roll damage

Nothing in the Repulsion Shield description indicates that you don’t take the damage from that hit, so the general rule still applies.

Compare to the *shield* spell:

> Until the start of your next turn, you have a +5 bonus to AC, *including against the triggering attack*

When a feature prevents the damage from an attack it will tell you, or in the case of the *shield* spell, will tell you that it can turn the hit into a miss.